# Finding an appropriate rectange in a 2-d array

Tags: python, algorithm, logic

Well, the title is not very appropriate, please read on (I couldn't get a better one).

Note: Using Python 2.7, but an algorithm will help too.

I'm making a side scroller game, in which I am generating the obstacles on the fly. The trouble I am having is figuring out how to generate the obstacles. o_O
I have a some kind of a logic, but then I'm having trouble in figuring out the entire logic.

So here's my problem from an implementation perspective :
I have a `Surface`, in which I have put some `Element`s, which are all rectangles.
Think of it like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

As in the above structure, how can I determine if a `axb` rectangle can be added without overlapping another rectangle (of 1s), and where all. Also, that with maintaining a distance of x elements (even diagonally) from all the other objects, that means the entire rectangle is  (x+3, x+4). Something like if `x=1, a=3, b=4`, there's only one possible arrangement:
(2s represent the new object)

```
2 2 2 0 0 0 0
2 2 2 0 1 1 0
2 2 2 0 1 1 0
2 2 2 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Basically, I need to find all the points, from which an rectangle of sides `a` and `b` can have it's, say, top-left corner. How this be achieved?

Note: Open to better ideas for generating the obstacles on the fly!

PS: I've asked this here and on Programmers as I think it falls on topic on both sites.

Comment: Please don't crosspost.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an algorithm, not existing code, and has been cross-posted to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206298/finding-possible-positions-for-rectangle-in-a-2-d-array

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't get why this is off-topic, but yes, shouldn't have cross posted.. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fairly well:

```
def find_valid_locations(grid, z, a, b):
    check = [(0, 0, 0, 0)]
    w = z + b
    h = z + a
    while check:
        x, y, ox, oy = check.pop()
        if x + w >= len(grid) or y + h >= len(grid[0]):
            continue
        for i, row in enumerate(grid[x+ox:x+w+1], x+ox):
            for j, val in enumerate(row[y+oy:y+h+1], y+oy):
                if val:
                    break
            else:
                continue
            check.append((x, j+1, 0, 0))
            if y == 0:
                check.extend((ii, j+1, 0, 0) for ii in range(x+1, i+1))
                check.append((i+1, y, 0, 0))
            break
        else:
            yield (x, y)
            check.append((x, y+1, 0, h-1))
            if y == 0:
                check.append((x+1, y, w-1, 0))
            continue
```

The brute force method here would be to check all positions in every potential rectangle location and only return locations where the rectange didn't encounter a non-zero position.  This is essentially what we do here, with the following optimizations:

- If we have found a valid location (x, y), we can check locations (x+1, y) and (x, y+1) easily, by only checking the new positions added to the rectangle by shifting it down or to the right.
- If we encounter an obstacle at position (i, j) while checking location (x, y), we can skip checking any other location that includes (i, j) by starting our next checks at (i+1, y) and (x, j+1).

Note that I renamed the parameter `x` to `z` so that I could use `x` as a row index in the code.

Comment: Wow! this is faster than I expected (and slower than I need) but is it possible to optimize this more? It took around 0.9 seconds, for a 7x7 grid, the other structure is 24x32, so that makes it significantly slower.. Giving me 1 FPS. :(

Comment: I added another optimization so that it will not ever try to check the same location twice, but I'm not sure it will help enough.  Not sure how your times could be right though unless you are calling this in a loop, even in the worse case for a 24x32 grid this never takes longer than a couple of ms for me.

Comment: Are you repeatedly calling this for different argument values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Yes.. Well, they are random numbers..

Comment: Ok.. (This is embarrassing) Sorry, that 0.9 was due to a while loop, made a mistake with the condition... Sorry.. Thanks.. This  works well..

Answer (score 0):

You can store the surface in a matrix M, then iterate over the matrix to find a place for the top-left corner of the new rectangle R:

```
for all rows of matrix M
    for all columns of matrix M
       variable empty = 0 
       for all numbers from 1 to a
            for all numbers from 1 to b
                empty = empty + M(row + a, col + b)                    
       if empty == 0
           insert R(row,col) //insert R with top-left corner at M(row,col)
           break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a brute force search which considers all possible placement of a rectangle a, b with border c in a grid which is a 2 dimensional Python list (a list of lists).

`find_placements` adds the width to the border and the height to the border before calling `isvalid`. This way `isvalid` doesn't need to consider anything about the border.

I used variable `a, b, c` for width, height, border so that they're not confused for coordinates which are usually `x, y, z` of something like that. `gx` and `gy` are short for grid x and grid y.

One discrepancy is that with with 2 dimensional lists representing a grid in this way, accessing a cell is done with `grid[y][x]` not `grid[x][y]`. Everything else is pretty straight forward though.

```
def find_placements(grid, a, b, c):
    """
    Return [(x, y), ...] for all valid placements in the grid
    of rectangle a x b with border c.
    """
    result = []
    for gx in xrange(len(grid[0]) - (a + c)):
        for gy in xrange(len(grid) - (b + c)):
            if isvalid(grid, (a + c), (b + c), gx, gy):
                result.append((gx, gy))
    return result


def isvalid(grid, a, b, x, y):
    """
    Return True if rect a, b fits at pos x, y
    without overlapping.
    """
    for gx in xrange(x + a):
        for gy in xrange(y + b):
            if grid[gy][gx]:
                return False
    return True
```

---

```
>>> grid =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
]
>>> find_placements(grid, 3, 4, 1)
[(0, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: This method is comparatively (much) slower than FJ's, 36.45 times slower...

Comment: I knew it was slow (brute force) although your OP didn't indicate that you were specifically looking for performance. This was just the simplest impl I could come up with. I'll think about a faster one though.